# Adding captions under images distrupts bootstrap image grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm making a simple product portfolio and using Bootstrap 3. Without captions my images look like this:

[image: Images without captions]

When I add captions under them they look like this:

[image: Images with captions]

I want them to stay like in picture one but with added captions below them.

Here is the HTML(with captions):

```
<div class="works-list type-one">
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach($proizvodi as $proizvod)
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="work-item">
                                <div class="wi-over">
                                    <h4>{{ $proizvod->naziv }}</h4>
                                    <ul class="clearfix">
                                        <li><a href="{{ $proizvod->slika_url }}" class="without-caption image-link"><img class="img-responsive"></img></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ route('proizvod', array($kategorija->slug, $proizvod->slug)) }}"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <img src="{{ $proizvod->slika_url }}" alt="Work Name" class="img-full-border">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                    <h5 style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px; text-align:center;">{{ mb_strtoupper($proizvod->naziv) }}</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                            {!! $proizvodi->render() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I'm using Laravel so blade code is included.

Here are the related css classes:

```
.works-list.type-one{
    margin-bottom           : -30px;
}
.works-list.type-one .row div[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom           : 30px;
}
.works-list.type-one .work-item{
    position                : relative;
}
```

This problem only occurs when the caption is longer than 1 line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a demo of the output?

Comment: @ManojKumar what do you mean, in jsfiddle or something else?

Comment: Anywhere as far as it can be produced. JSfiddle is fine.

Comment: I cannot get it right to show you the problem in jsfiddle. My code generates for example 10 products each one encapsulated in a div of class col-md-4 etc. You can see the problem from the screenshots.

Comment: Yes, we can help you if you reproduce the issue. Lots of copy paste task for us to do. Not sure if the error can be seen as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I managed to make this one: https://jsfiddle.net/owqtsyza/

Comment: Do you have a live website?

Answer (score -1):

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! While this piece of code might be the solution to this special instance of the problem, and the OP might be satisfied, it would be great if you could include some lines of explaination, so further readers with a similar problem can benefit from it, too! [-- from Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16030732)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)